# How is an HTTP request via a proxy different from a normal request?

Tags: windows, http, proxy

In Windows one sets a value in Registry when one wants to define a proxy. When using the WinHttpRequest object, one can specify an application-level proxy.

What is actually happening at the HTTP request/response level?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to identify whether http request is from browser or from proxy server (or server)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143458/how-to-identify-whether-http-request-is-from-browser-or-from-proxy-server-or-se)

Comment: The other question doesn't answer what I'm asking. I want to construct a header which uses a proxy server. I want to know how it is different from a standard header.

Comment: It's part of a larger problem: I can specify application-level proxies when using XMLHttpRequest, but I'd like to be able to do application-level proxies when using InternetExplorer.Application. There's a header specification as the fourth element of the Navigate method. I'm wondering if I can use that to form the correct header for a proxied navigation.

Comment: The OP of the other article wants to know if he can tell whether the traffic he has received comes from a proxy. I'm a bit further upstream.

Comment: Why don't you update your question with your actual question then? :-) It's a bit unclear what you're asking or what problem you're actually trying to solve. You can't however just set a header to make a regular request become a proxy request.